# Powershell ScriptBlock with 'cmd /c' and '$using' inconsistent behavior

Tags: powershell

My code:

```
Clear-Host

$installed_softwares = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
    Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*" } | Select-Object -Property *

$csv = Import-Csv('C:\<...>\softwares.csv')

$softwares_to_remove = @()
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $info = New-Object System.Object
    $info | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $line.Software
    $info | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Version -value $line.Version
    $info | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Publisher -value $line.Publisher
    $softwares_to_remove += $info
}

ForEach ($installed_software in $installed_softwares) {
    ForEach ($software_to_remove in $softwares_to_remove) {
        If ($software_to_remove.Name -eq $installed_software.DisplayName -And $software_to_remove.Version -eq $installed_software.DisplayVersion -And $software_to_remove.Publisher -eq $installed_software.Publisher) {
            Write-Host 'Tring to remove:' $installed_software.DisplayName, $installed_software.DisplayVersion, $installed_software.Publisher, $installed_software.UninstallString

            If (($installed_software.UninstallString).ToLower() -match '^msiexec') {
                Write-Host 'Skipped: ' $installed_software.DisplayName
                Write-Host ''
            } Else {
                # Working: .\<SOFTWARE>\uninst.exe /S
                $full_path = $installed_software.UninstallString
                if ($full_path -like '* *') {
                    if ($full_path -notlike '"*') {
                        $full_path = '"' + $full_path + '"'
                    }
                }

                write-host $full_path, $full_path.GetType()

                Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { cmd /c $using:full_path /S}
                Write-Host 'Removed:' $installed_software.DisplayName
                Write-Host ''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Tring to remove: BitComet 1.36 1.36 CometNetwork C:\Program Files (x86)\BitComet\uninst.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\BitComet\uninst.exe" System.String
Removed: BitComet 1.36

Tring to remove: qBittorrent 3.3.14 3.3.14 The qBittorrent project "C:\Program Files (x86)\qBittorrent\uninst.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\qBittorrent\uninst.exe" System.String
Removed: qBittorrent 3.3.14

Tring to remove: Steam 2.10.91.91 Valve Corporation C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\uninstall.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\uninstall.exe" System.String
Removed: Steam

Tring to remove: Viber 6.8.6.5 Viber Media Inc. MsiExec.exe /I{05247C1B-0AD7-43B0-B6F9-D29B376ADC9A}
Skipped: Viber
```

Currently, I'm running it locally via Powershell ISE started as Local Adminisrator, but the idea is to run this remotely when it's done. Sometimes the only software that gets uninstalled after I run this script many times is `qBittorrent`, but it doesn't do it flawlessly as it leaves the entry inside "Add/Remove Programs" in Control Panel, if it were a manual uninstall this wouldn't happen.

Why this code have this inconsistent behavior? How to fix it?

Comment: So, after reading through your issue and code... it sounds like your main issue/question is that it remains within the control panel's GUI for `Add/Remove Programs`.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, from the list of softwares I gave, only `qBittorrent` got uninstalled, but even this one wasn't removed completely as the entry is still there inside Control Panel. All the others softwares were not even uninstalled, nothing changed in theirs folders at all.

Comment: `Import-Csv` already assigns your variable an object.  Why are you then creating another object to deal with it?

Comment: To tell you the truth, that's the least of my problems. Reading from the files is working so I won't change it now. I need to get the whole code working first, then I'll optimize it...